# Facebook remember me

Tags: facebook

I want to implement a "remember me" feature on me website using the facebook connect.

On my website, i have the possibility to do the login by two distinct ways:

- Normal login
- Facebook Connect

When an user performs the login with facebook connect, even if he logs out on his facebook account, i want to keep him logged in on my website. He will only log out if he clicks on the logout button on the website.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a tutorial](http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/tutorial.php) using PHP that demostrates how to use Facebook connect. If you read the [section about the login page](http://www.goldsteintech.com/facebook_connect/login_page.php), you'll see that Facebook does some funky javascripting that creates session cookies on your domain based on the login status on Facebook. You might be able to manipulate the API to give yourself the persistance that you're looking for.

Good luck, and hope this helps some in your project.

Comment: Thanks, you've gave me some ideas